# Not able to relogin facebook after logging out

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments

I integrated facebook login to my Android App. I was able to login when I launch the Application, but when I logout and come back to initial screen to login again ,it does not login I was taken to Home screen of mobile . But when I relaunch the app again from launcher and try to login, I am able to login.But with in the App , when I try to relogin it does not login.

 For information , I used custom button to login into facebook.

The below is the code :

**Fragment and OnCreate() Method**

```
  public class SocialFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

 private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
 private ProfileTracker profileTracker;
 private CallbackManager callbackManager;


 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            initializeFaceBook();

    }
```

**//Initilization of Facebook SDK**

```
 private void initializeFaceBook(){
        Log.d(TAG,"initializeFacebook.......");
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

      accessTokenTracker= new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {
                 Log.d(TAG,"onCurrentAccessTokenChanged()");
            }
        };

        profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile) {
                //displayMessage(newProfile);
                Log.d(TAG,"onCurrentProfileChanged()");
            }
        };

        accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
        profileTracker.startTracking();
    }
```

**//Custom Button Click to login Facebook**

```
private void fbLogin(){
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
    }
```

**//OnCreateView() method that contains Layout**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_social, container, false);
        mContainerId = container.getId();

        ImageButton fBook = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.fbook);
        fBook.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }
```

**//OnClickMethod()**

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.fbook:
                 fbLogin();
                //onFblogin();
                break;


        }
    }
```

**//OnActivityResult**

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

**//On Destroy**

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "In onDestroy().........");
        profileTracker.stopTracking();
        accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
    }
```

**//Launch New Fragment**

```
private void displayMessage(Profile profile){
        if(profile != null){
            Log.d("PROFILE", profile.getName());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Facebook Profile Name:::" + profile.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(mContainerId,new BikePoolerMapFragment()).commit();
        }
    }
```

**//OnResume()**

```
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        displayMessage(profile);
    }
}
```

**Logout used in another Fragment:**

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

Can anyone help me is relogin the facebook with in app. 
Is there a way in which to logout facebook other than the way I used.

**Facebook SDK used : 4.8.2
Android Studio is used**

Comment: whats the error you get when you try to login again? Can you paste the log here ?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and the solution in my case was to make sure that the instance of the CallbackManager is the right one.

the singleton that manages the facebook had the wrong instance of the CallbackManager, therefor the callback wasn't fired.

hope it helps.

using Android Studio with SDK 4.8.2